# Using & and + in asp.net with vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some confusion as to the use of + and & in ASP.NET and VB.NET. See the following code:

```
Dim dtUser As DataTable = GetDetails()
        Dim serverPath As String = Nothing
        Dim virtualServerPath As String = Nothing
        Dim parentDir As DirectoryInfo = Nothing
        Dim childDir As DirectoryInfo = Nothing
        serverPath = Page.Server.MapPath(".") + "\"
        virtualServerPath = serverPath.Substring(0, serverPath.LastIndexOf("\"))
        virtualServerPath = virtualServerPath + "\SiteImages\" + dtUser.Rows(0)("Name")
        parentDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(virtualServerPath)
        childDir = parentDir.CreateSubdirectory(Session("RegID"))
        Dim strUserName as String=dtUser.Rows(0)("Name")
        If flUpload.HasFile Then
            flUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" & dtUser.Rows(0)("Name") & "/" & childDir + "/" + flUpload.FileName))
```

I am getting error concerned with usage of + and & in

```
 flUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" & strUserName & "/" & childDir + "/" + flUpload.FileName))
```

Can anybody help to remove the error

Comment: See my answer below.  This question apparently has nothing to do w/ & and +, apparently they are interchangable, although I would never use + with string concat in VB.

Answer (score 3):

Use "&" for concatenation, "+" will work until you have a value that a mathematical operation can be performed on in the concatenation. It will attempt to perform the addition rather than concatenation.

eg.

```
"blah" & "blah" works
"blah" + "blah" works
"blah" & 5 works
"blah" + 5 fails
```

The last one does not work as it will try to "add" 5 and a string

Comment: Also I don't think you can mix them in the same statement. if you try to perform "blah" & "blah" + "blah" it will fail as it will attempt to add the last string.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know VB string concatenation uses &, **don't use +**

"A" & "B" & "C" = "ABC"

"A" + "B" + "C" =  hmmm error? (Edit) apparently this works...

(More Edit)...

**Possible answer to your error:**

**I don't think the error is anything to do with & or + now.
It might be your `childDir` which is of type `DirectoryInfo`.  You might want to get the name of the directory in it instead of just plopping childDir in the string concat.**

try change it to & `childDir.Name` in that concat.

Comment: apparently + is working also... Hmm... I didn't know that :)  Never used it when I was doing VB 6 back then.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
flUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" & 
                        dtUser.Rows(0)("Name") & 
                                           "/" & 
                                      childDir + 
                                           "/" + 
            flUpload.FileName))
```

to

```
flUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/" & 
                        dtUser.Rows(0)("Name") & 
                                           "/" & 
                                      childDir & 
                                           "/" & 
            flUpload.FileName))
```

and pay heed to @CodeWiki's comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129424/using-and-in-asp-net-with-vb/1129458#1129458) answer that is not to mix *+* and *&* in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

In VB, the `&` is for string concatenation.  You should only use `+` for addition operations.

The problem with `+` is that it tries to do implicit conversion so you can do

```
 2.5 + 5
```

C# would give you an error because 2.5 would be a `float` and 5 would be an `int`.  You would need to cast them.  VB does the casting implicitly which can hide some bugs.

Comment: you just need to adjust the Compiler options for the project in Visual Studio to Warn or cause exception for those situations...it may not be a default though.